# String assignment has incomplete type

Tags: c, string, variable-assignment, incomplete-type

I have a shared library that takes a new prompt (for the shell) as a parameter `argv[1]` I also have a global variable prompt type string as such

```
char *prompt[];

int setprompt(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    prompt = argv[1];
    return 0;
}
```

and I'm getting the following error

> setprompt.c:14:2: error: ‘prompt’ has an incomplete type
>
> prompt = argv[1];
>
> ^

Comment: If `prompt` is supposed to point to the prompt string, then its type should be `char *`, not `(char *)[]`.  In any event, the latter is indeed an incomplete type because it does not specify the number of elements in the array (of `char *`).

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
char *prompt[];
```

you did not supply a size for the array.

Quoting `C11`,chapter §6.7.6.2

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type.  [...]

Only time you're allowed to do that when you supply an initializer list, otherwise, you have to specify the size explicitly.

As per your  requirement, making `prompt` a `char *` will suffice.

Comment: IIRC it is also allowed as the last data member of a struct.

Comment: @juanchopanza absolutely sir, but that has to be a member of the `struct`. Nevertheless, it will be an incomplete type, isn't it? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, you are absolutely correct.  The standard in fact puts it in exactly those terms: "As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member." (C2011, 6.7.2.1/18)

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a global or local with that syntax, since it denotes an array of unspecified size.  Such a declaration is fine as a function parameter, since the array decays into a pointer.

In your case, you want a pointer, not an array of pointers:

```
char *prompt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be declared as a pointer:

```
char *prompt;
```

This argument passed to the function `char *argv[]` is an array of pointers, and you are assigning to your global pointer just one element from that array.